# How do I create a method that takes any iterable collection of strings?

Tags: julia

I have a function, `f`. I want to add a method that takes any container of `String`s. For example, I want to write a method that generates the following when needed:

```
f(xs::Array{String, 1}) = ...
f(xs::DataArray{String, 1}) = ...
f(xs::ITERABLE{String}) = ...
```

Is this possible to do in Julia's type system? Right now, I'm using a macro to write a specialized method when I need it.

```
@make_f(Array{String, 1})
@make_f(DataArray{String, 1})
```

This keeps things DRY, but it feels...wrong.

Comment: I am using `f(xs...)`, so at call site `f(my_array...)`, `f(my_tuple...)`

Answer (score 6):

Can't you just use duck typing? I.e., just *assume* that you're feeding the function an object of the right type and throw an error if at some point e.g. you don't have a string in your iterable.

This should improve once you can really talk about iterables using traits; currently there is no iterable type. Scott's answer, for example, will not work with a tuple of strings, even though that is iterable.

E.g.

```
julia> f(x) = string(x...)  # just concatenate the strings
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(("a", "á"))
"aá"

julia> f(["a", "á"])
"aá"

julia> f(["a" "b"; "c" "d"])  # a matrix of strings!
"acbd"
```

Comment: I was specializing on a function that already had several specialized methods. And, I didn't want to add a tag or anything for proper dispatch. 

P.S. It's cool seeing twitter followers (you and Scott) are the one's answering!

Answer (score 3):

At least in Julia 0.4, the following should work:

```
julia> abstract Iterable{T} <: AbstractVector{T}

julia> f{T<:Union{Vector{String},Iterable{String}}}(xs::T) = 1
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x = String["a", "é"]
2-element Array{AbstractString,1}:
 "a"
 "é"

julia> f(x)
1
```